# Define user macros in different property sheet

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is it somehow possible to do following:

`branch.prop`:

```
// excerpt
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <Branch>Trunk</Branch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And another property sheet, `common.prop`:

```
// excerpt
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir>D:\output\$(Branch)\VW$(VW_VERSION)\$(KN_BUILD)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>D:\output\$(Branch)\VS_Output\$(VW_VERSION)\$(KN_BUILD)\$(ProjectName)\</IntDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Problem**

The problem is, that I use both property sheets in my project and if I show my projects properties I see that it shows the correct output directory and intermediate directory (like e.g. ' D:\output\Trunk\VW2016\Debug\' ) but when I compile my project it does not work, meaning that the user macro is missing so that logs show lines like following:

```
Library "D:\output\\VS_Output\2016\Debug\SomeProject\SomeProject.lib" ...
```

*Pay attention to `\\` instead of `\Trunk\` in the log line!*

Is there some way that property sheets work with user macros defined in different property sheets? Something like nesting them e.g. or any other trick?

I want to avoid to define my output directory and intermediate directory in each project manually (which would work)...

**NOT WORKING ALTERNATIVE IDEAS**

- use a prebuild script that reads out the current svn path and setting an environment variable => because the environment variable is only read by VS on VS start, so if the prebuild script changes it VS does not recognise this until it is restarted

**Why do I need this**

I need this because I'm forced quite often to switch between trunk and a branch to create a hotfix and so want to avoid long build times because of overwriting intermediate / output files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your `branch.prop` in `common.prop`, like this:

```
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" >
    <Import Project="branch.prop"/>
</ImportGroup>
```

Comment: That looks great, can this be done with the IDE as well or only manually?

Comment: Ok, after knowing that this works and exists, I found out how to do this with the IDE: simply right click a property sheet and click "add existing property sheet", this will add it underneath.